# Opening activity from main

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I am getting an error where it says "Error:(52, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected"
I am trying to make it so that when the button is clicked it sends a message in xml to open another activity.
this is my xml code for the button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Period 1"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:paddingStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#33cbff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:paddingEnd="80dp" /><![CDATA[

/>
```

and this is the java in the main activity that is being underlined in red.

```
 public void sendMessage(View view){
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Period1.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

it is the "MainActivity.this, Period1.class" that is underlined in red
Period1 is the new activity I want to open

Comment: why added this line in xml : <![CDATA[

/>

Comment: Can you add the code from Period1.class?

Comment: <![CDATA[  remove this line

Comment: I think that you have an extra closing brace before the sendMessage method

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the above posted code, I guess you might have written the sendMessage method outside your MainActivity class. If so please write that function inside the MainActivity class declaration.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Your code

  public void sendMessage(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Period1.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.